# encrypt decrypt files with safer in r

Tags: r, encryption

Has anyone been able to get safer to encrypt and decrypt files? I'm not getting an error. It returns true 3 times. If I add a path to all the files in the code and create an iris.csv file it deletes the iris.csv file. Or is there another option in r to encrypt/decrypt files? [GitHub safer](https://github.com/talegari/safer)

```
library(safer)
# symmetric case:
write.table(iris, "iris.csv")
all(
  encrypt_file("iris.csv", outfile = "iris_encrypted.bin")
  , file.exists("iris_encrypted.bin")
  , decrypt_file("iris_encrypted.bin", outfile = "iris_2.csv")
  , file.exists("iris_2.csv")
  , tools::md5sum("iris_2.csv") == tools::md5sum("iris.csv")
  , unlink("iris.csv") == 0
  , unlink("iris_2.csv") == 0
  , unlink("iris_encrypted.bin") == 0
)

## [1] TRUE

write.table(iris, "iris.csv")
all(
  encrypt_file("iris.csv", outfile = "iris_encrypted.txt", ascii = TRUE)
  , file.exists("iris_encrypted.txt")
  , decrypt_file("iris_encrypted.txt", outfile = "iris_2.csv", ascii = TRUE)
  , file.exists("iris_2.csv")
  , tools::md5sum("iris_2.csv") == tools::md5sum("iris.csv")
  , unlink("iris.csv") == 0
  , unlink("iris_2.csv") == 0
  , unlink("iris_encrypted.txt") == 0
)

## [1] TRUE

# asymmetric case:
alice <- keypair()
bob   <- keypair()
write.table(iris, "iris.csv")
all(
  encrypt_file("iris.csv", alice$private_key, bob$public_key, outfile = "iris_encrypted.bin")
  , file.exists("iris_encrypted.bin")
  , decrypt_file("iris_encrypted.bin", bob$private_key, alice$public_key, outfile = "iris_2.csv")
  , file.exists("iris_2.csv")
  , tools::md5sum("iris_2.csv") == tools::md5sum("iris.csv")
  , unlink("iris.csv") == 0
  , unlink("iris_2.csv") == 0
  , unlink("iris_encrypted.bin") == 0
)

## [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the package encryptr? https://encrypt-r.org/

Comment: It doesn't look like you can encrypt an R file. ???